# Return success message or error message from AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, form

I´m constructing a form to get new emails from my website.

The form works fine, all fields are recorded at data extension. :)

But i have problems to return the success message or error message from AMPscript, the code apparently are ok. (think i)

What i´m doing wrong ?

[ ] ´s best regards.

```
var url = "http://pages.S7.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=MY_ID";
var params = "";
params = $("#formcadastra").serialize();
//alert(params);
$.post(url,params, function(data) {
    data = data.substring(0,(data.indexOf("}",0)+1));
    var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(jsonObj.status == "Ok") {
      alert("ok!"); 
    } else {
      alert("no ok!");
    }
});
```

AMPscript code

```
%%[
    VAR @NOME, @EMAIL, @CELULAR, @CPF, @SEXO, @OPTIN
    SET @NOME = RequestParameter("nome")
    SET @EMAIL = RequestParameter("email")
    SET @CELULAR = RequestParameter("celular")
    SET @CPF = RequestParameter("CPF")
    SET @SEXO = RequestParameter("sexo")
    SET @optin = RequestParameter("optin")

    IF @optin == 'sub_add_update' THEN
        SET @OPTIN = 'TRUE'
    ELSE
        SET @OPTIN = 'FALSE'
    ENDIF

    SET @affected_rows = UpsertData
    (
    "Teste_23",1,
    "Nome",@NOME,
    "Email",@EMAIL,
    "Celular",@CELULAR,
    "CPF",@CPF,
    "Sexo",@SEXO,
    "optin",@OPTIN
    )
    IF @affected_rows > 0 THEN
        SET @status = "Ok"
    ELSE
        SET @status = "Error"
    ENDIF
]%%
{ 
    "status":"%%=v(@status)=%%",
    "affected_rows":"%%=v(@affected_rows)=%%"
}
```

Comment: When you created the page with the AMPscript... did you make sure the content type was JSON?

Comment: You should post what the page actually returns.